# plotting score in the Pac-Man model in NetLogo

Tags: plot, netlogo, pacman

A seemingly simple question,
How can I plot the "score" in the "Pac-Man" model in NetLogo

I have tried the obvious approaches (adding a Plot to the interface, telling it to "plot score").
The problem I seem to be having is that the variable for “score” in the Pac-Man game isn’t returning a value to the plot - however it is returning a value elsewhere in the program (the "Score" monitor at the top of the model.

More info available here: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/Pac-Man
(though you won't be able to add the new Plot)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: after adding your plot, add [`update-plots`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#update-plots) to the top of the `play` procedure.  Like this:

```
to play  ;; Observer Forever Button
  update-plots
  ;; Only true at this point if you died and are trying to continue
  if dead?
...
```

Normally in NetLogo plotting seems to happen automatically because most models are tick-based, and they rely on calling [`tick` in a `go` procedure to update the plots](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#tick).  This model is not tick-based, which is perfectly fine, but then we have to add the call to `update-plots` explicitly while it runs to get our plots updating.